# Openpyxl - how to create sequential sheets with names

Tags: openpyxl

I have a list = ['A17','A18','P08','P09','P10','C03'], and wanted to create worksheets in the workbook and assign worksheets to ws variable:

```
for i in list:
     ws = wb(i)
```

but how do I get to ws1 = wb['A17'], ws2 = wb['A18'], etc.

Thanks

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to add ['A17','A18','P08','P09','P10','C03'] as multiple cells on a single row? Or add it to the first column, along multiple rows?

Comment: I wanted to use looping to create worksheets within a workbook and name the worksheets after the elements in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a worksheet with the following syntax `wb.create_sheet(title='test')`. It will return the worksheet.

If you want to create sheets using a list, then simply call a for each loop. `[wb.create_sheet(title=x) for x in list]`. This will return an array of worksheets.

**For example:**

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

list = ['A17','A18','P08','P09','P10','C03']
wb = Workbook()
workskheets = [wb.create_sheet(title=x) for x in list]
wb.save("output.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thank you, Greg! It worked. Is there a reference for openpyxl that goes over all these? I googled before I posted.

Comment: The documentation is here https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html